# Can i use the dealloc() method in ARC in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, dealloc

I am a newbie in objective-c

I have a lot of memory issues, and a lot of alloc variables

-what to do?

Comment: can I use it ? Yes. Can I override it ? No.

Comment: how do you know you have memory issues?

Comment: it is showing the memory warnings in the debug area

Comment: @TejaNandamuri What? The only way to "use" it is to override it. Just with ARC you can't call '[super dealloc]'.

Comment: so if we write -(void)dealloc{....} in a class without super call. It doesn't mean that we are overriding the dealloc right ? @rmaddy

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Implementing `dealloc` is overriding it whether you call `super` or not. It's just that ARC doesn't allow you to call `super`.

Comment: ahh I see.All these days I'm under wrong assumption. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in Objective-C in contrast to functions methods are nor called (but invoked via a dispatch) neither using `()` . The typical spelling for a method is `-dealloc`. Sending a message to execute it, is done with `[]` as in `[self dealloc]`.

No, you cannot do this. Your code will break.

> You never send a dealloc message directly. ([Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/dealloc))

If you have memory leaks with ARC, the reason are retain cycles. Read [something](https://www.google.de/?client=safari#q=retain%20cycle%20objective-c) about it. Most retain cycles are easy to detect. However, you can use the Instruments (Allocations) to detect them at runtime.

Comment: thanks a lot, you helped me very well. But the thing is that :  
Let's say we have three objects: a grandparent, parent and child. The grandparent retains the parent, the parent retains the child and the child retains the parent. The grandparent releases the parent.

What will happen in this case ?

Comment: parent and child will leak, because they refer each other and are unreachable. This *is* a retain cycle. Break it.

Comment: break it means what exactly? I searched for it but didn't get the right idea. Do you have any reference?

Comment: In your case typically the reference from the child to the parent is built weakly, using the keyword `weak`. In such a case the parent would lose its last reference (the reference from child is weak), therefore will be deallocated, what takes away the last reference to the child, so it is deallocated, too.

Answer (score -1):

When you will use ARC, you can not call dealloc ([super dealloc]). The compiler handles it for us. you can refer this [link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#dealloc) for more details :

You can use @autoreleasepool for better practice.